# Errors while inserting pandas dataframe to a table due to foreign key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am performing a very simple operation of taking up values from one table processing it and loading to an empty table in Postgres.

The first table has the following structure :

```
CREATE TABLE public.entities
(
  canonical character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  db_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  code character varying(255),
  description character varying(4096),
  level character varying(255),
  class character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  model character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'test'::character varying,
  variants text[],
  CONSTRAINT entities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (db_id, canonical, class, model)
)
```

The second table where I am trying to load the processed data has the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE public.entities_variants
(
  entitymodel_canonical character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  entitymodel_db_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  entitymodel_model character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  entitymodel_class character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  variants character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT fk8g9miq5xcx1jtp85lysrkjhm FOREIGN KEY (entitymodel_canonical, entitymodel_db_id, entitymodel_model, entitymodel_class)
      REFERENCES public.entities (db_id, canonical, class, model) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Now when I am trying to insert(either row wise or the entire dataframe) I am getting integrity error:

> IntegrityError: insert or update on table "entities_variants" violates
>   foreign key constraint "fk8g9miq5xcx1jtp85lysrkjhm" DETAIL:  Key
>   (entitymodel_canonical, entitymodel_db_id, entitymodel_model,
>   entitymodel_class)=(Timothy Dress, 92002, ofirmev, Name) is not
>   present in table "entities".

where I have confirmed that this data exists in the first table as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of columns you're defining your foreign key doesn't match the order you're referencing the columns.

You have `entitymodel_canonical` referencing `db_id`, `entitymodel_db_id` referencing `canonical`, etc.

I think your constraint statement should be:

```
CONSTRAINT fk8g9miq5xcx1jtp85lysrkjhm FOREIGN KEY (entitymodel_db_id ,entitymodel_canonical, entitymodel_class, entitymodel_model)
  REFERENCES public.entities (db_id, canonical, class, model) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```